# Где эффективнее ставить фильтрующее условие при соединении таблиц?

Tags: sql, oracle

Предположим, есть таблицы TABLE_1 и TABLE_2. Мы хотим их сджойнить. Но при этом, мы мы знаем, что нет нужды джойнить всю таблицу TABLE_1, отсекая по дате нужные строки (может даже индекс есть на столбце с датой). Так вот. У нас есть два варианта джойна:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 T1
  JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.COL_1 = T2.COL_1
WHERE T1.COL_DATE between to_date(...) and to_date(...);
```

И другой вариант

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 T1
  JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.COL_DATE between to_date(...) and to_date(...)
    AND T1.COL_1 = T2.COL_1;
```

Какой вариант эффективнее и по какой логике? Или вообще без разницы и запрос будет оптимизирован автоматически?

Comment: Оптимизатор сам разберется

Comment: Для INNER JOIN без разницы - это просто разные синтаксические формы одного и того же запроса. И я даже не представляю, в каких условиях у них будут разные планы выполнения. А если LEFT JOIN - то это разные запросы, которые дадут разные результаты.

Comment: @Akina добро, а в случае LEFT JOIN какой запрос был бы эффективнее и почему?

Comment: Я бы выбрал первый вариант просто потому что он легче читается. В объединении - условия объединения, в where - фильтры.

Comment: @Akina, по-моему и в случае с left join результат будет одинаковым

Comment: @MaxU В данном конкретном случае - да, я погорячился. Результат действительно будет одинаков. Потому как дополнительные условия, переносимые из WHERE в ON, накладываются на первую таблицу. И что самое забавное, как раз в случае LEFT JOIN второй вариант может при определённых условиях оказаться эффективнее.

Comment: @Akina Нет, в случае left join и переноса условия в ON результат будет совершенно другим. Из первой таблицы будут выбраны вообще все записи. А вот вторая таблица будет подклеена только в случае если дата из первой будет в интервале.

Comment: Чёта у меня сегодня голова не на месте :(

Comment: Так выходит, что разницы вообще нет? Я то думал, что в первом варианте он отсекает сперва по дате, а потом приклеивает к тому что есть вторую таблицу. А во втором варианте он берет вообще все строки, но подклеивает только к тем, что в интервале. Но при inner join из полученной таблицы берет только успешно склеенные. То есть второй случай звучит дольше. В общем-то, вопрос был для разрешения этого внутреннего конфликта в моей голове :3

Comment: То что вы описываете, это так людей обучают, для понимания запросов. Машине этого не не сказали. Оптимизатор строит план исходя из статистики по таблицам, конкретный синтаксис ему до лампочки (почти). Я видел кучу примеров, когда даже подзапрос exists давал абсолютно такой же план как и join.

Comment: Да, но план показывает, что он всю таблицу использует. Плак-плак Т_Т А индекса не оказалось, вот думаю может навесить раз такое дело. Дополняться вроде бы только в конец должно.

Comment: Ну индексы конечно нужны. А если две таблицы связаны, так они просто обязаны быть. и foreign key должен быть. Но кстати использование индекса не панацея. Оптимизатор запросто может от него отказаться и выполнить например какой нибудь merge join, если посчитает что так быстрее. И если он так посчитает он еще и прав часто оказывается

Comment: @Mike, да все правильно. Не поленился и [проверил на практике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/945181/211923) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь идет о `INNER JOIN`, что эквивалентно просто `JOIN`, то запросы вернут одинаковый результат, но первый вариант лично мне кажется более понятным.

Исходные таблицы:

```
SQL> select * from a;

        ID       COL1
---------- ----------
         1         11
         2         12
         3         13

3 rows selected.

SQL> select * from b;

        ID       COL2
---------- ----------
         1        111
         3        333
         5        555

3 rows selected.
```

Пример для `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM a t1
JOIN b t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  4  WHERE t1.col1 between 12 and 13;

        ID       COL1         ID       COL2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3         13          3        333

1 row selected.

SELECT *
FROM a t1
  3  JOIN b t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.col1 between 12 and 13;

        ID       COL1         ID       COL2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3         13          3        333

1 row selected.
```

---

Для `LEFT OUTER JOIN` логика меняется потому что предикат `WHERE` будет исполнен уже после объединения, а в объединение (*до фильтрования* - применения предиката `WHERE`) попадут все строки из левой таблицы.

Пример для `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (синоним `LEFT JOIN`):

```
SELECT *
FROM a t1
LEFT JOIN b t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.col1 between 12 and 13;

        ID       COL1         ID       COL2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3         13          3        333
         2         12

2 rows selected.

SELECT *
FROM a t1
  3  LEFT JOIN b t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.col1 between 12 and 13;

        ID       COL1         ID       COL2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3         13          3        333
         1         11
         2         12

3 rows selected.
```